# Object not writing to JSON in javascript when ussing Object.assign

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, react-native

I am trying to add a value to a temporary JSON obtained from firebase database that contains user information, so that I can get the username added to the called post value without actually putting the username into the post JSON to save data. I ma having an issue where the Object.assign method creates a new field in the JSON, but nothing in the field is written. How would I fix this issue?
My code is below:

```
getPosts = (limit = 20) => {
    var list = [];
    firebase.firestore()
      .collection("posts").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          var userName = "";
          firebase.firestore().collection("users").where('email', '==', doc.data().email).get().then((querySnapshot) =>
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc2) => {
                userName = doc2.data().name;
              }
            )
          );
          var tempList = doc.data();
          console.log(tempList);
          Object.assign(tempList, {
            "userName": userName
          });
          console.log(tempList);
          list.push(tempList);  
        });
        list.sort(function(a, b) {
          var c = b.timestamp;
          var d = a.timestamp;
          return c - d;
        })
        this.setState({
          data: list,
          fullData: list
        });
      });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.func;
      resolve(_.take(this.state.fullData, limit));
    });
  };
```

This code is a function in react native. It works basically off of javascript so all syntax is the same. Any help would be largely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn't look like it would work in JS either. Are you sure you posted the same code?

Comment: What is console.log showing for tempList? Is that object or array?

Comment: I am sure this code prints out the Jason of user data but after the objects call, only the key is shown with no value but an empty string

Comment: The console.log is showing an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong in several parts. You can't expect a promise to resolve before you run the next statement after the `then()` clause.

Use `aysnc/await` instead. I didn't test this code, but you could do something like this:

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collection("posts").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        var userName = "";
        var tempList = doc.data();
        const usersQs = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").where('email', '==', doc.data().email).get();
        usersQs.forEach(doc2 => (userName = doc2.data().name));
        tempList.userName = userName;
        list.push(tempList);
      });
```

Comment: This surprisingly worked for me. Thank you! Also, when I implement this code, my feed continually refreshes and only shows the FlatList elements for a second, and then they dissapear until I relead again. How would I fix this?